# Debug symbols won't load for slc.dll and sppc.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols, pdb-files

Here is my situation.  I'm trying to debug a WCF service on a remote server (Windows 2012 R2 Standard). I'm on a Windows 7 Professional System running Visual Studio 12.   After figuring out how to install the remote debugger and connect to it, I received a Symbols not loaded error.  After finding the Module Window, I found that I had only 4 of 93 PDB files found (my project PDBs).  After much research, I discovered the Symbols window in the Options menu and made sure that I had a Cache Symbols Directory set up and that the Microsoft Symbol Servers as one of my locations.  After clicking Load all symbols, VS 2012 loaded all but two files, sppc.pdb and slc.pdb.

I've run symchk *.* /r and received the following output:

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)>symchk *.* /r

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 221
```

Someone on a different forum suggested using the symchk command to try to specifically load the PDB file from the Microsoft Symbol server.  So when I ran that I got the following:

```
SYMCHK: slc.dll              FAILED  - slc.pdb mismatched or not found
```

So I checked to see if I was using it right.  I ran the following and downloaded many PDBs into a temp directory but not the ones I needed:

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)>symchk /r C:\windows\system32 /s srv*C:\Temp\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

*** Some output removed for brevity  ***

SYMCHK: slc.dll              FAILED  - slc.pdb mismatched or not found
SYMCHK: snacnp.dll           FAILED  - SnacNp.pdb mismatched or not found
SYMCHK: sppc.dll             FAILED  - sppc.pdb mismatched or not found
```

So I ran syschk against one of the files verbosely to see if that would tell me anything:

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)>symchk /v C:\windows\system32\slc.dll
[SYMCHK] Searching for symbols to C:\windows\system32\slc.dll in path C:\Temp\Symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: C:\Temp\Symbols
[SYMCHK] Using search path "C:\Temp\Symbols"
DBGHELP: No header for C:\windows\system32\slc.dll.  Searching for image on disk

DBGHELP: C:\windows\system32\slc.dll - OK
SYMSRV:  C:\Temp\Symbols\slc.pdb\BEC5C21CFFE144E48E70042F52FF1D271\slc.pdb not found
DBGHELP: slc - no symbols loaded
[SYMCHK] MODULE64 Info ----------------------
[SYMCHK] Struct size: 1680 bytes
[SYMCHK] Base: 0x000007FF70190000
[SYMCHK] Image size: 45056 bytes
[SYMCHK] Date: 0x4a5be063
[SYMCHK] Checksum: 0x00011b30
[SYMCHK] NumSyms: 0
[SYMCHK] SymType: SymNone
[SYMCHK] ModName: slc
[SYMCHK] ImageName: C:\windows\system32\slc.dll
[SYMCHK] LoadedImage: C:\windows\system32\slc.dll
[SYMCHK] PDB: ""
[SYMCHK] CV: RSDS
[SYMCHK] CV DWORD: 0x53445352
[SYMCHK] CV Data:  slc.pdb
[SYMCHK] PDB Sig:  0
[SYMCHK] PDB7 Sig: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
[SYMCHK] Age: 0
[SYMCHK] PDB Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] DBG Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] Line nubmers: FALSE
[SYMCHK] Global syms:  FALSE
[SYMCHK] Type Info:    FALSE
[SYMCHK] ------------------------------------
SymbolCheckVersion  0x00000002
Result              0x00010001
DbgFilename         slc.dbg 
DbgTimeDateStamp    0x00000000
DbgSizeOfImage      0x00000000
DbgChecksum         0x00000000
PdbFilename         slc.pdb
PdbSignature        {BEC5C21C-FFE1-44E4-8E70-042F52FF1D27}
PdbDbiAge           0x00000001
[SYMCHK] [ 0x00000000 - 0x00010001 ] Checked "C:\windows\system32\slc.dll"
SYMCHK: slc.dll              FAILED  - slc.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0
```

I know that these files are part of the Software Licensing Client and while I know no reason that they would need to be loaded for debugging the fact of the matter is that VS wants it.

Anyone have any ideas how I get the PDBs or suppress the need for the symbol files to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't provide the PDBs for SLC to prevent creating of cracks to activate Windows.

Run the VS2012, go to `Options`->`Debugging`->`autoamtically load symbols for: "all symbols, unless excluded"`. Click on the blue link and add SLC to the exclude list.

Now VS skips loading the PDB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried your steps and all files either have a status of Symbols loaded or Loading disabled by Include/Exclude.  However the breakpoints still won't load because "No Symbols have been loaded for this document

Comment: post some pictures of the error. Maybe you mixed release/debug configs